# Reading JSON_decode in PHP -- results not displayed

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to parse the symbols from the JSON below:

```
$trending_url = "https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/trending/symbols/equities.json";
```

Example response here:

```
{
    "response": {
        "status": 200
    },
    "symbols": [{
        "id": 11631,
        "symbol": "JNUG",
        "title": "Direxion Daily Jr Gld Mnrs Bull 3X Shrs",
        "is_following": false
    }, {
        "id": 9553,
        "symbol": "NUGT",
        "title": "Direxion Daily Gold Miners Bull 3X Shrs",
        "is_following": false
    }, {
        "id": 12100,
        "symbol": "BABA",
        "title": "Alibaba",
        "is_following": false
    }]
}
```

From above JSON-- i would like to extract the symbol's (i.e. JNUG, NUGT, BABA) through a loop. Here's what i did...

```
$trending_url_info = json_decode(file_get_contents($trending_url),true);

echo $trending_url_info->symbols->symbol[0] . "<br>";
echo $trending_url_info->response->symbols->symbol[0] . "<br>";
echo $trending_url_info->response->symbols[0]->symbol[0] . "<br>";

echo $trending_url_info['response']['symbols'][0]['symbol'] . "<br>";
echo $trending_url_info['response']['symbols'][0]['symbol'][0] . "<br>";
echo $trending_url_info['response']['symbols']['symbol'][0] . "<br>";
```

However none of the echo's above give me the symbol. How do i have a loop and extract the symbol's from the JSON feed? Any help is appreacited.. thanks.

Comment: If you write $trending_url_info = json_decode(file_get_contents($trending_url),true);
in this 'true' meaning, it will return associative array, once print_r($trending_url_info) and check type whether its an object or array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple demonstration of the correct access to those properties:

```
<?php
$jsonInput = <<<EOT
{
    "response": {
        "status": 200
    },
    "symbols": [{
        "id": 11631,
        "symbol": "JNUG",
        "title": "Direxion Daily Jr Gld Mnrs Bull 3X Shrs",
        "is_following": false
    }, {
        "id": 9553,
        "symbol": "NUGT",
        "title": "Direxion Daily Gold Miners Bull 3X Shrs",
        "is_following": false
    }, {
        "id": 12100,
        "symbol": "BABA",
        "title": "Alibaba",
        "is_following": false
    }]
}
EOT;

$jsonData = json_decode($jsonInput);
foreach ($jsonData->symbols as $symbol) {
  var_dump($symbol->symbol);
}
```

The output obviously is:

```
string(4) "JNUG"
string(4) "NUGT"
string(4) "BABA"
```

Answer (score 2):

`symbols` is not under `response`. That is why `$trending_url_info['response']...` none of these are working. Also `json_decode` with `true` gives you associate array not an object.

`$trending_url_info['symbols'][0]['symbol']` this should work.

```
$trending_url_info = json_decode(file_get_contents($trending_url),true);

$symbols = array();

foreach($trending_url_info['symbols'] as $sym) {
    $symbols[] = $sym['symbol'];
}

echo(json_encode($symbols));
```

`$symbols` will give `[JNUG, NUGT, BABA]`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$trending_url = {
    "response": {
        "status": 200
    },
    "symbols": [{
        "id": 11631,
        "symbol": "JNUG",
        "title": "Direxion Daily Jr Gld Mnrs Bull 3X Shrs",
        "is_following": false
    }, {
        "id": 9553,
        "symbol": "NUGT",
        "title": "Direxion Daily Gold Miners Bull 3X Shrs",
        "is_following": false
    }, {
        "id": 12100,
        "symbol": "BABA",
        "title": "Alibaba",
        "is_following": false
    }]
}

foreach($trending_url->symbols as $obj){
  echo $obj->symbol."<br>";
}
```